# Move through input text when fill or empty them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm implementing a 2-factor authentication on my website login and I would create a page like the 2-factor authentication page of apple with 6 text input, one for each code. These input permit to move ahead and forward if I fill or empty it.
I tried to do but I had a lot of problems.

1. When all inputs are filled, and I am in the last one and try to delete with "backspace", it remove the previous and not the last.
2. When I move the cursor on a filled input, it goes automatically to the next.

```js
$(".digit-input").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.digit-input').focus();
  }
  verificaSePieno();
});

$(".digit-input").keydown(function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).text() == "") {
    $(this).prev('.digit-input').focus();
  }
  verificaSePieno();
});

function verificaSePieno() {
  if ($("#digit1").text() != "" && $("#digit2").text() != "" && $("#digit3").text() != "" && $("#digit4").text() != "" && $("#digit5").text() != "" && $("#digit6").text() != "") {
    $("#submitBtn").removeClass("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#submitBtn").addClass("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digits">
  <input id="digit1" name="digit1" class="digit-input" data-indx="0" data-next-id="digit2" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit2" name="digit2" data-prev-id="digit1" class="digit-input" data-indx="1" data-next-id="digit3" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit3" name="digit3" data-prev-id="digit2" class="digit-input" data-indx="2" data-next-id="digit4" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit4" name="digit4" data-prev-id="digit3" class="digit-input" data-indx="3" data-next-id="digit5" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit5" name="digit5" data-prev-id="digit4" class="digit-input" data-indx="4" data-next-id="digit6" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit6" name="digit6" data-prev-id="digit5" class="digit-input" data-indx="5" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all of your problems come from this wrong condition :

```
$("#digit").text() != ""
```

This expression return always False. Use instead:

```
$("#digit").val() != ""
```

Your code now seems to work:

```js
$(".digit-input").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.digit-input').focus();
  }
  verificaSePieno();
});

$(".digit-input").keydown(function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == "") {
    $(this).prev('.digit-input').focus();
  }
  verificaSePieno();
});

function verificaSePieno() {
  if ($("#digit1").val() != "" && $("#digit2").val() != "" && $("#digit3").val() != "" && $("#digit4").val() != "" && $("#digit5").val() != "" && $("#digit6").val() != "") {
    $("#submitBtn").removeClass("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#submitBtn").addClass("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digits">
  <input id="digit1" name="digit1" class="digit-input" data-indx="0" data-next-id="digit2" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit2" name="digit2" data-prev-id="digit1" class="digit-input" data-indx="1" data-next-id="digit3" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit3" name="digit3" data-prev-id="digit2" class="digit-input" data-indx="2" data-next-id="digit4" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit4" name="digit4" data-prev-id="digit3" class="digit-input" data-indx="3" data-next-id="digit5" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit5" name="digit5" data-prev-id="digit4" class="digit-input" data-indx="4" data-next-id="digit6" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit6" name="digit6" data-prev-id="digit5" class="digit-input" data-indx="5" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".digit-input").keyup(function(e) { console.log( e.which)
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength && e.which!=37) {
    $(this).next('.digit-input').focus();
  }
  verificaSePieno();
});

$(".digit-input").keydown(function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == "") {
    $(this).prev('.digit-input').focus();
  }
  verificaSePieno();
});

function verificaSePieno() {
  if ($("#digit1").val() != "" && $("#digit2").val() != "" && $("#digit3").val() != "" && $("#digit4").val() != "" && $("#digit5").val() != "" && $("#digit6").val() != "") {
    $("#submitBtn").removeClass("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#submitBtn").addClass("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digits">
  <input id="digit1" name="digit1" class="digit-input" data-indx="0" data-next-id="digit2" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit2" name="digit2" data-prev-id="digit1" class="digit-input" data-indx="1" data-next-id="digit3" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit3" name="digit3" data-prev-id="digit2" class="digit-input" data-indx="2" data-next-id="digit4" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit4" name="digit4" data-prev-id="digit3" class="digit-input" data-indx="3" data-next-id="digit5" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit5" name="digit5" data-prev-id="digit4" class="digit-input" data-indx="4" data-next-id="digit6" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit6" name="digit6" data-prev-id="digit5" class="digit-input" data-indx="5" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>
```

Hope this will solve your second issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect but something like this.

```js
$(function(){
 nextEmpty(); //select first empty field
 $(".digit-input").on("input", handleInput) //for values
             .on("keydown", handleKey); //for backspace
  
  function handleInput(e){    
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if(len){
      if( $(e.currentTarget).index() == 5 ){
    setTimeout(function(){
          alert( "code is:" + getCode() ); //all fields are filled
        }, 10);
      }else{
       next(e);
      }
    }
  }
  function handleKey(e){
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if(e.which == 8 && len === 0){
     setTimeout(function(){ prev(e); }, 10);
    }
  }
  
  function prev(e){
    var $cur = $(e.currentTarget);
    var target = $cur.index() - 1;
    $(`.digits input:eq(${target})`).focus().select();
  }
  function next(e){
    var $cur = $(e.currentTarget);
    var target = $cur.index() + 1;
    $(`.digits input:eq(${target})`).focus().select();
  }
  function nextEmpty(){
   $(".digits input[value='']").filter(":first").focus();
  }
  function getCode(){
    var sb = "";
    $('.digits input').each(function(){
     sb += $(this).val();
    });
    return sb;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digits">
  <input id="digit1" name="digit1" class="digit-input" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit2" name="digit2" class="digit-input" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit3" name="digit3" class="digit-input" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit4" name="digit4" class="digit-input" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit5" name="digit5" class="digit-input" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <input id="digit6" name="digit6" class="digit-input" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>
```